# how to reopen and interrupt keyboard stream?

Tags: java, multithreading, io, stream

I have a very simple question.
Based on Java I/O scheme, whenever a thread is waiting for some data, so it will be blocked? is it true? something like this.

```
byte[] _buff=new byte[1024];
int _r=_in.read(_buff);//it blocks until some data is available
```

and the just possible way to give up reading is closing the stream by another thread, is it right? something like this.

```
void run(){
_in.close();
}
```

so if I am right with above scenarios, so why this is impossible just interrupt a thread which is reading from `System.in` by closing the stream. I run a thread that just waits for 5 seconds then wants to interrupt/give up rest of the reading from the stream.

```
void _read_data(){
  System.out.print("enter y to save the workspace ");
  new Thread(_cancel_thread).start();
  int _r=System.in.read();//blocks
}
///////////
void run(){
  try{
   Thread.sleep(5000);
   System.in.close();//doesn't work.
  }catch(Exception _ex){}
}
```

**Questions:**
1.How to close the stream?! why the closing stream thread cannot close the stream?!
2.Once the stream got closed, how to open it again?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first question, I think this is because maybe(I don't know, not sure) the stream is kinda locked by lower-level, so while it's locked, another thread is just waiting to acquire the lock and close it.
and for second one, I really don't know is there any class(stream) which works with keyboard stream or not, but why do you really want to close it? just keep the stream somewhere (like `in=System.in`), then redirect the standard stream to another stream by calling `System.setIn(newStream)`, then whenever you want to give keyboard stream back, reset the stream with the reference.
Closing the default system input stream is not good idea, I suggest you utilize either `JConsol` or `jNativeHook`, these guys do not block, instead they listen for events.